# am5charts pie of pie change the legend color text to red

Tags: colors, fonts, pie-chart, amcharts, amcharts5

How can I change the font color of the text below? my background is dark.

my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/theg99/2vsnmb16/1/

I did mange to change the colors of the lines with:

```
var line0 = container.children.push(
  am5.Line.new(root, {
    position: "absolute",
    stroke: root.interfaceColors.get("text"),
    strokeDasharray: [2, 2],
    stroke: am5.color('#0xFFFFFF'), //<--I added this, but whats for text?
  })
);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this should work:

```js
subSeries.labels.template.set("fill", am5.color(0xff0000));
```

This changes all the labels on your second chart - is that what you're looking for?
[image]